# Removing file from .git directory from previous commit

Tags: git

I have added `charges.txt` file of 64 MB size in `git` repository and did `commit` ( let `git` gave me `commit` hash **id x** ).
Following above `commit`, I have also did around 20 more commits to `git` repository with different changes in each `commit`.

Now I Found that I have added wrong `charges.txt` file into `git` repository.
I have removed it using `git rebase` interactively to my previous `commit` **id x** but I have noticed that the files are removed from my working directory but it's not removed it from `.git` directory as the size of `.git` folder is almost same before and after my `git rebase`.

Please suggest me the right way to remove the file completely from `.git` as well to reduce my repository size? Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove/delete a large file from commit history in Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100907/how-to-remove-delete-a-large-file-from-commit-history-in-git-repository)

Comment: It sounds like you've already removed the file from your git history, and are now just trying to reclaim disk space? If that's the case, a simple `git gc` should do the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagine you deleted your file and the commit accidentally. Git still enables you to undo your mistake by keeping your commits for a certain period of time — the default period is 90 days. This is a good thing.

You can edit the expiration period using the following command:

`git reflog expire --expire=time`

Git periodically runs a garbage collection, cleaning up the repository and optimising it. It is considered bad practice to run garbage collect manually and if you are not entirely sure that you know what you are doing, I would suggest simply leaving it be. The 64mb of space will show up eventually. If you still would like to remove that commit, try the following:

```
git reflog expire --expire-unreachable=now --all
git gc --prune=now
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Thomas

Comment: You're welcome, Sekhar. If this was the answer your were looking for, please consider marking it as "Accepted Answer". :)

Comment: What you said seems correct, But when I did the steps you mentioned still the file is not deleted permanently. I am Still missing something ?

Answer (score 0):

The [BFG Repo Cleaner](https://help.github.com/articles/removing-sensitive-data-from-a-repository/) should solve your problem. Use it like:

```
bfg --delete-files YOUR-FILE-WITH-UNWANTED-DATA
```

But be carefull and backup your repo first.